# How to lost focus of TextBox with clicking on form

Tags: c#, textbox, lost-focus

I have Two TextBox txtBox1 and txtBox2. and txtBox1 has LostFocus Event.
When my focus is in txtBox1 and go to txtBox2 at that time txtBox1's LostFocus event works well .

But my problem is that when my focus is in txtBox1 and I click anywhere on form at that time txtBox1's LostFocus event is not call. I mean How can I lost focus of txtBox1 with clicking on form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its pretty tricky, you can create an invisible control to give focus to but really at least one control is supposed to have focus, what is it you are hoping to do with this?

Comment: Code `Form.Mouseclick`maybe like this: `if (txtBox1.Focused) txtBox2.Focus();`. Focus has to be somewhere..

Answer (score 1):

When trying to lose focus from a textbox when clicking somewhere in the form I always create a 'dummy' textbox or an invisible textbox.  Something like this...

```
<TextBox x:Name="DummyTB" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Width="0" Height="0" />
```

Just add that where you want the dummy textbox to be located.  And then in the code behind add...

```
DummyTB.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `Form.Select()` and `Form.Focus()` does not unselect any other control that is on the form.

A invisble dummy textbox is not possible since this control would have `this.CanFocus` set to `false`.